Swift unexpected behaviour using SwiftData
With the code below:
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  DataTest
//
//  Created by Felipe Cruxen on 06/07/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Director {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
class Movie {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var director: Director?
    init(name: String, director: Director? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.director = director
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    @Query private var movies: [Movie]
    @Query private var directors: [Director]
    @State private var movie: Movie = Movie(name: "")
    @State private var director: Director = Director(name: "")
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(movies) { movie in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Movies at \(movie.name)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(movie.name)
                        Button("-") {
                            deleteMovie(movie: movie)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 180, ideal: 200)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addDirector) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            List {
                ForEach(directors) { director in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Directors at \(director.name)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(director.name)
                        Button("-") {
                            deleteDirector(director: director)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
           
        } detail: {
            TextField("Movie Name", text: $movie.name)
            Picker("Director", selection: $movie.director) {
                ForEach(directors, id: \.self){ director in
                    Text("\(director.name)").tag(director as Director?)
                }
            }
            Button(action: addDMovie) {
                Label("Add Movie", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            
            TextField("Director Name", text: $director.name)
            
            Button(action: addDirector) {
                Label("Add Director", systemImage: "plus")
            }
        }
    }

    private func addDirector() {
        withAnimation {
            modelContext.insert(director)
            try? modelContext.save()
            director = Director(name: "")
        }
    }
    
    private func addDMovie() {
        withAnimation {
            let toSave = movie
            modelContext.insert(toSave)
            movie = Movie(name: "")
        }
    }

    private func deleteDirector(director: Director) {
        withAnimation {
            modelContext.delete(director)
            try? modelContext.save()
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteMovie(movie: Movie) {
        withAnimation {
            modelContext.delete(movie)
            try? modelContext.save()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}

there's a weird error, whenever selecting the director the in the picker, the movie gets added to the list of movies. Auto save is disabled. This does not occur when editing the textfield for movie or director, only when selecting the director in the picker. It should only be persisted when calling the function, isn't it? Checking the sqlite database I can confirm the movie is not persisted, when restarting the app the movie entry vanishes.
Before picking the director:

After picking the director:

Searched on google, and asked chatGPT, so now I am asking for the help of humans

Up to my knowledge, you can't have multiple queries in one view, because there is only one model container.

Is it 100% neccesarry to use SwiftData? Because that is a fairly new framework with lots of bugs. I could make a solution without SwiftData, but you will have to give me the full code including the "Item".

@KarlEhrlich You can certainly have multiple query properties in a view.

@JoakimDanielson You are completely right, my bad

What you see is expected behaviour actually. When you assign a model (Director) object to a relationship property of another (Movie) object SwiftData will check if any of the objects (but not both) in the relationship is inserted into a ModelContext and then automatically insert the other one as well in the same context.
So in this case it will see that the selected Director is inserted and directly insert the Movie object.
There are several ways to avoid this if it's an issue like splitting the functionality of creating movies and directors into two different views or instead if directly working with properties for the models
@State private var movie: Movie = Movie(name: "")
@State private var director: Director = Director(name: "")

you can use properties for the names instead
@State private var movieName = ""
@State private var directorName = ""

and then create the actual objects only when you are about to save them, so in addDMovie() and addDirector()
